# rotate my ios app using UIInterfacOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I used to allow rotate my ios app in ipad:
[image]

My issue is the white space in the right in landscape orientation, but in portrait is well.
I think that I put a condition if the orientation in landscape or in portrait and adjust the width of the view controller, but how can I adjust it? and what shall the condition be?

Please help!

Comment: Learn to use Autolayout,Layout inspector or Layout Autoresize

Comment: How can I use it? can u give me an example please for my issue

Comment: How are you drawing your view?  Is that a UITableView?  Are you doing custom drawing?  Are you arranging stuff in Interface Builder or are you doing it programatically?

Answer (score 0):

Here are macros UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape and UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait

so rather checking separately you can do it like this ...

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
    // code for landscape orientation      
}
OR

 if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
 {
     // code for Portrait orientation       
 }
```

After check the orientation. you can apply condition.
and also please read autosizing

Comment: can u tell me in which method should I put it

Comment: you can put it in Viewdidload